# System shuts down immediately after few sconds

Tags: hardware-failure

I have a computer with following specification and was working fine after re-installing the system and refitting sink fan unit.

Recently it shuts down automatically after a few seconds. I checked PSU by shorting pin no.s 13 & 14 as well as 14 & 15. It worked well means the PSU fan moves. But I never checked the voltages at different wires.

I refitted the heat sink fan by applying thermal paste. but it behaved the same. Again I refitted the Heat Sink Fan, then it worked for 2 minutes and again shut down.

Now it shuts down immediately after switching on.

```
Mother board  : M26GTM-3VP
CPU : AMD athlon
PSU : 450 watt
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the processor is over-heating.

Wait approximately 15 minutes to half an hour for the computer to cool down.

I would recommend re-applying the thermal paste and re-seating the cpu fan along these guidelines: http://benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=170&Itemid=1

The easiest way to check if your CPU is overheating is by booting directly into BIOS, once cooled down, and then going to the processor tab. The temperature should be displayed in Celsius as one of the data lines.

Comment: Don't forget to remove old scorched dust from the heat-sink, if there is any. Make sure the CPU fan is rotating and that you have firmly attached the heat-sink it to the motherboard.